# Understanding difference between Amazon Web Services and GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, amazon-web-services

I'm learning how to develop a web mapping application for multiple GIS layers (vector and raster). As I'm learning about each component when configuring every element works (GIS desktop, RDBMS, web server, geospatial server, tiling, APIs), I'm hitting a roadblock in conceptually understanding how to choose and implement a server system.

AWS comes highly recommended from colleagues, but I'm getting confused how it works. I know it's a cloud server, so does this mean I can store/host my GIS data (tiles, WMS) on there? How is it different from GeoServer?

I can't get past understanding the functionality of those two systems.

Comment: AWS is an entire server in the cloud - such as a Windows or Linux server operating system; on which you can run a database server such as PostgreSQL/PostGIS, then run a web server such as Apache, then run Geoserver to serve up your map data...

Comment: @DPSSpatial that actually helps a lot, thank you! What are alternatives to Apache?

Comment: Here's a tutoral for [Setting up your first GeoServer instance](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog865/node/7) on AWS.

Comment: Apache is analogous to Windows IIS as a web server - but here are some alternatives: http://slodive.com/web-development/lightweight-alternatives-to-apache-and-iis-web-servers/

Answer (score 10):

[AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is-aws/) is a set of virtualized hardware that looks like a computer to you and others.

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/about/) is a piece of software that converts spatial data into web maps, it can run on an AWS instance.